# Designer failing because parent form "does not have property named..."

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance

I have a form called 'CustomForm' that I use so that I have a consistent design across all forms I make.  All the child forms inherit from it simply as in 'class childForm : CustomForm'.  I removed the windows border on the custom form and made my own, and so I have label for the window title.  I created a protected property that modifies that label's text.

For some reason when I try to open the designer of a child form it says:

> The type 'Quiz.CustomForm' has no property named 'WindowTitle'.

I want to be able to edit this property via the designer in the 'Misc' section of the the form properties.  This worked before and I don't know what I've done to disturb it.  If I go into the designer file, and into InitalizeComponent, it says 'this.WindowTitle = "The string here"'.  And there is no error because I have created a protected property for it in the parent form.  There is no underlining by the IDE, but yet I receive the above error when I try to load the designer.

The property in the CustomForm class looks like:

```
protected string WindowTitle
    {
        get { return lbl_windowTitle.Text; }
        set { lbl_windowTitle.Text = value; }
    }
```

I tried making the property public but it made no difference.

Comment: @IvanStoev OP claimed that they tried that without difference in the last sentence

Comment: @rene Although I'm pretty sure non public properties does not show in the Properties grid, so there is no way to *edit it via the designer*. So definitely the problem is caused by the property not being `public`, regardless of the OP claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This worked before and I don't know what I've done to disturb it.

I'm pretty sure your (currently `protected`) `WindowTitle` property was `public`, otherwise there is no way to see/edit it in the form Properties - the design time support (and `System.ComponentModel` in general) works only with **public** properties.

I performed similar actions and was able to get the same error.

> I tried making the property public but it made no difference.

It will make a difference. Just **rebuild** your project after making the property `public` and the problem will disappear.

Comment: You're right.  I did try making it public, but didn't rebuild the project which may have caused the continuing issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You've said that you have tried with a public property, but using it and the property attributes should work fine as in this sample I've made: https://www.dropbox.com/s/45blckvgiz460h7/WindowsFormsApplication1.rar?dl=0

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
    {
        public BaseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Base Form")]
        [Description("Define the window title.")]
        public String WindowTitle
        {
            get { return label1.Text; }
            set { label1.Text = value; }
        }
    }
```